# When is Mindfulness Based Cognitive Therapy not useful, or bad?

Tags: emotion, metacognition, meditation

I'm writing my Bachelor on MBCT, and while there are a ton of studies on the positive effects of mindfulness and MBCT, I'm wondering if there are any cases where MBCT shouldn't be applied. I've found some litterature on certain possible negative effects of mediation, but nothing on MBCT specifically.

So, do anyone know of studies or research papers that mentions cases where MBCT is not useful or should be avoided?

Comment: Could you include the reference on negative effects of 'mediation' (possibly 'meditation' was intended)?

Answer (score 2):

The mindfulness stress buffering account (Creswell, Lindsay, 2014) suggests that mindfulness practice  buffers acute stress reactivity, therefore it has more impact on health outcome of a high-stress group than a low-stress group.

Creswell, J. D., & Lindsay, E. K. (2014). How Does Mindfulness Training Affect Health? A Mindfulness Stress Buffering Account. Current Directions in Psychological Science, 23(6), 401–407. https://doi.org/10.1177/0963721414547415